# How can I use the verb run in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I have a sentence that goes: "Measurements are run for 2 hours". Is it correct?

Perhaps, I should use the verb "process" instead of "run"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say *measurements are taken for two hours* or *measurements are processed for two hours*.

If you would use *run* (supposing the verb is correct), then *are run* is correct; you don't say *are ran*.

Comment: I also think *run measurements* may be idiomatic if what is spoken of is a measurement process of long duration (*this measurement takes two hours to run*), or a stereotyped battery of measurements (*we run an exhaustive series of measurements on every unit that leaves the shop*).

Comment: I edited that sentence, since I just wanted to say that "are run" is correct, and "are ran" is not correct.